# Setting Up Relationship Between Tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

```
class UsersLite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mkt_users"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    user_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    email_id = Column(String(75))
    public_key = Column(String(64000))
    org_type = Column(String(75))
    user_status = Column(String(75))

    teams = relationship("TeamMappingLite",
                         primaryjoin="and_(TeamMappingLite.user_id == UsersLite.user_id)",
                         lazy='joined',
                         viewonly=True
                         )

    team_names = relationship("TeamsLite",
                              secondary="mkt_user_team_mapping",
                              primaryjoin="and_(UsersLite.user_id == TeamMappingLite.user_id, "
                                          "TeamMappingLite.team_id == TeamsLite.team_id)",
                              secondaryjoin="TeamsLite.team_id == TeamMappingLite.team_id",
                              viewonly=True,
                              uselist=True
                              )

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.user_id)


class TeamsLite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mkt_teams"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    team_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    team_name = Column(String(75), unique=True)
    team_owner = Column(String(75))
    team_status = Column(String(75))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.team_id)


class TeamMappingLite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mkt_user_team_mapping"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    mapping_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(UsersLite.user_id), index=True)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TeamsLite.team_id), index=True)
    status = Column(String(75))


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.mapping_id)
```

For the above tables, i need to setup relationship between these three tables. In UsersLite in **team_names** I should be able to get the team names from TeamsLite table, the teams and users are mapped in TeamMappingLite, Or in **teams** only i should get the team name.

Expected Response:

```
{
     ......userdetails,

    "teams": [
      {
        
        "team_name: "ABCD",
        "status": "REVOKED",
        "mapping_id": 4,
        "stamp_updated": "2023-06-15T18:20:30",
        "user_id": 1,
        "team_id": 4,
        "stamp_created": "2023-06-15T17:38:49"
      },
```

I have tried it, but what i am able to get is teams only with team*id and user*id